# Border radius of selection list of DropdownButtonFormField in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I didn't find how to decorate the list that appears when you click on DropdownButton like make radius for the corners as you see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You want to dropdown is like rounded corner?

Comment: yeah the list that appears when clicking DropDownButton have a rounded corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [flutter 2.11.0-pre](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) the native `DropdownButtonFormField` comes with `borderRadius` by default.

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  items: // <your items list>
  value: // your value
  onChanged: (value) {}
)
```

You could consider updating your flutter version to 2.11.0+, just keep in mind it's still in beta.

Comment: It would be better if u could format the code

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. [`DropdownButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Add `borderRadius` property to `DropdownButton`

```
String dropdownValue = 'One';
```

**your Widget**

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),//change value on your need
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  elevation: 16,
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
```

Your result-> [image]

Comment: i'm using DropdownButtonFormField that doesn't contain borderRadius,

Comment: i nned to use DropdownButtonFormField  because i'm using form

Comment: Ok Wait I will try

Comment: look i is an issue in git https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/95944